# How to Wrap By Words in Prawn Table

Tags: ruby, prawn

I would like to create a prawn table where cell text is wrapped by words and not letters. I am already using shrink_to_fit, but it seems that prawn is wrapping based on letters. I would ideally want it to wrap on words alone (single_line is not an option since there can be 2-3 words per cell).

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your table contains words that are too long for a single table cell? As far as I know, table cells in Prawn tables use bounding boxes which should wrap the text automatically. The following example works fine for me:

```
Prawn::Document.generate 'example.pdf' do
  data = [['Pig','Oink '*10],
          ['Cow','Moo '*10],
          ['Duck','Quack '*10]]
  table data do |table|
    table.column_widths = [50,150]
  end
end
```

If nothing works, you could try building your own table with multiple  [text_box](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text.html#method-i-text_box) calls instead of using the built-in [Prawn table method](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Table.html), this is of course a bit cumbersome. `text_box` draws the requested text into a box. The `:overflow` parameter controls the behavior when the amount of text exceeds the available space, available options are `:truncate`, `:shrink_to_fit`, or `:expand`.

```
text_box(txt, :at => [x,y], :width => width, :height => height, :size => size,
              :overflow => :shrink_to_fit,..)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply :) If you change to 'data = [['Pig','Hello There '*10],' in the first line of your data, you will see that you will get the same problem that i am getting. The word 'there' is wrapped incorrectly. I will also take a closer look at text_box now, thank you for your reply anyway, +1.

Comment: As i also state in the question, i am already using shrink_to_fit, but this one does per character and not per word wrapping, which is pretty much what the whole problem is about.